# HiveContext not working from Oozie

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, oozie, hivecontext

I was trying to run some hive queries from my spark code using the HiveContext object. It was working fine when I run it from the command line using spark submit. But, I am getting the below exception when I try to run the same from a oozie workflow.

```
User class threw exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add the Hive sharelib to the Spark action if Hive classes are used.
You can set the following property either in oozie-default.xml, in the workflow or in the action configuration:

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>oozie.action.sharelib.for.spark</name>
      <value>spark,hive</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I updated the workflow with the above property and the workflow was a success. But, I was not able to find the tables that I was creating.

Comment: You may have to insert the hive-site.xml into the workflow's <job-xml> tag and into Spark using the --file pathi/to/hive-site.xml in the <spark-options> tag.